# Html select POST Django

Tags: python, django, forms, orm, materialize

Hello i'm new to django.

I have a model that looks like this.

**Models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
pass

first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username

class Campus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Intervention(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    begin_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
    end_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    speaker = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    campus = models.ForeignKey(Campus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Intervention'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Interventions'

def __str__(self):
    return self.subject

class Evaluation(models.Model):
    interventions = models.ForeignKey(Intervention, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    speaker_knowledge_mark = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)])
    speaker_teaching_mark = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)])
    speaker_answer_mark = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)])
    slide_content_mark = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)])
    slide_examples_mark = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)])
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Evaluation'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Evaluations'
```

So, basically what i'm trying to do is on home page i want to have a select box where student have to choose his campus then he will be redirected to a new page where **he can see only the interventions that belongs to the campus he choosed**

**My home page looks  like this:**

[image: Homepage screenshot]

```
<form method="post" action="/Mark/"/>
    <select name="campus_id">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your Campus</option>
      {% for camp in campus %}
      <option value="camp.pk">{{ camp.name }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

I tried several things but none worked :/ if anybody can help or give me a hint.

Thanks.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a clear idea and define the flow:

- You have a view that displays the form to select the campus (alternatively you might have a list of links)
- Create a view (ListView) that displays a table (list) of Interventions
- Create a Django form with choices from your Campus model
- The view (FormView) that will process this form would get the selected value and redirect to another view using the provided value (id).
- List items provided by the Intervention display view (ListView) filtered (get_queryset) by the respective campus id